# Error while trying to migrate database (slalchemy, slqite3)

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, alembic

I have the next models.py file:

```
from app import db, bcrypt
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship


class BlogPost(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "posts"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    desc = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))

    def __init__(self, title, desc):
        self.title = title
        self.desc = desc

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Titulo >> " + self.title

class User(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    posts = relationship("BlogPost", backref="author")

    def __init__(self, name, email, password):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.password = password

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Usuario >> ", self.name
```

Then I ran:

```
python manage.py db init
```

and everything was fine, the thing is when I tried to modify my models file to make a migration.. I just change the line:

```
self.password = password
```

to:

```
self.password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password)
```

and when I ran:

```
python manage.py db migrate
```

it works, but when I tried to upgrade with:

```
python manage.py db upgrade
```

I get the next error:

```
"No support for ALTER of constraints in SQLite dialect")
NotImplementedError: No support for ALTER of constraints in SQLite dialect
```

Note: the database just has a few records for testing.. thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alembic has changed how SQLite migrations are done since most tutorials for Alembic were written.  `ALTER` commands now need to use [batch mode](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/batch.html).  This mode is still compatible with other databases, if you decide to switch from SQLite later.

For each table being altered, place all operations inside a `with op.batch_alter_table('table_name'):` block.

```
def upgrade():
    with op.batch_alter_table('table_name'):
        op.alter_column(...)
```